# Vaadin-grid export to CSV with lazy loading

Tags: javascript, vaadin-grid

I have to create a button that exports a Vaadin-grid as a CSV file.
But if the table has too many entries it starts to do lazy loading / paging and it only exports the loaded entries.
How do i export the entire table in those cases?
I'm pretty new to javascript and all i could find where java solutions that disable lazy loading entirely (which is not optimal since most tables are very big)

here is the exporter class:

```
    export class TableCSVExporter {

  constructor(table, content, includeHeaders = true) {
    this.table = table;
    this.content = Array.from(content.querySelectorAll('vaadin-grid-cell-content'));
    this.rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr'));


    if (!includeHeaders && this.rows[0].querySelectorAll('th').length) {
      this.rows.shift();
    }
  }

  convertToCSV() {
    const lines = [];
    const numCols = this._findLongestRowLength();
    console.log(this.content);
    let l = 0;
    let rows = this.content.length / numCols;

    // const row of this.rows
    for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      let line = '';

      for (let i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        if (y == 0) {
          line += TableCSVExporter.parseHeaderCell(this.content[l]);
        } else {
          line += TableCSVExporter.parseCell(this.content[l]);
        }
        l++;
        line += (i !== (numCols - 1)) ? ',' : '';
      }


      lines.push(line);
    }

    return lines.join('\n');
  }

  _findLongestRowLength() {
    return this.rows.reduce((l, row) => row.childElementCount > l ? row.childElementCount : l, 0);
  }

  static parseCell(tableCell) {

    let parsedValue = tableCell.textContent;

    return this.formatCellContent(parsedValue);
  }


  static parseHeaderCell(tableCell) {
    let parsedValue = "";

    let input = tableCell.querySelector('vaadin-text-field');

    if(input != null) {
      parsedValue = input.placeholder;
    }
    return this.formatCellContent(parsedValue);
  }

  static formatCellContent(parsedValue) {
    // Replace all double quotes with two double quotes
    parsedValue = parsedValue.replace(/\n/g, '');
    parsedValue = parsedValue.replace(/"/g, `""`);
    parsedValue = parsedValue.trim();

    // If value contains comma, new-line or double-quote, enclose in double quotes
    parsedValue = /[",\n]/.test(parsedValue) ? `"${parsedValue}"` : parsedValue;
    return parsedValue;

  }

}
```

and this is the table class:

```
    import {
  LitElement, html,
} from 'lit-element';
import { render } from 'lit-html';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-grid/theme/material/vaadin-grid';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-grid/theme/lumo/vaadin-grid';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-filter';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-sorter';
import './theme/vaadin-grid';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-context-menu/vaadin-context-menu';
import { createGridOutput } from '../../../js/LdGlobal';
import { LdGridStyles } from './styles';

import '../modules/assets/assets-charts/availability/swimlane';
import '@polymer/paper-button/paper-button';
import '@polymer/paper-fab/paper-fab';
import { TableCSVExporter } from './TableCSVExporter';

/**
 * Displays a &lt;vaadin-grid&gt; element with given items
 * @extends LitElement
 */
class LdGrid extends LitElement {

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  static get properties() {
    return {
      gridItems: { type: Object, hasChanged: () => true },
      gridTitle: { type: String, hasChanged: () => true },
      gridColumns: { type: Object, hasChanged: () => true },
      multiSort: { type: Boolean, value: false, hasChanged: () => true },
      loading: { type: Boolean, value: false, hasChanged: () => true },
      userInformation: { type: Object, hasChanged: () => true },
      _height: { type: String, hasChanged: () => true },
    };
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  static get styles() {
    return [LdGridStyles];
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('keyup', () => this.calculateHeight());
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  updated(changedProperties) {
    if (changedProperties.has('gridColumns')) {
      if (changedProperties.get('gridColumns') === this.gridColumns) {
        this.calculateHeight();
      }
    }
  }


  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  render() {
    const gridColumns = [];
    this.gridColumns.forEach(item => {
      if (!item.hidden) {
        let _contextMenuOptions = '';
        let _contextMenuPrefix = '';
        let _contextMenuField = '';
        let _contextMenuSuffix = '';
        const _column = {};
        let _contextMenuOptionsLength;
        let _contextMenuLinksLength;
        if (item.icon) {
          _column.style = typeof item.icon.style !== 'undefined' ? item.icon.style : '';
          _column.src = typeof item.icon.src !== 'undefined' ? item.icon.src : '';
          _column.title = typeof item.icon.title !== 'undefined' ? item.icon.title : '';

        }

        if (item.link) {
          _column.link = {};
          _column.link.prefix = typeof item.link.prefix !== 'undefined' ? item.link.prefix : '';
          _column.link.suffix = typeof item.link.suffix !== 'undefined' ? item.link.suffix : '';
          _column.link.field = typeof item.link.field !== 'undefined' ? item.link.field : '';
        }

        _column.subkey = typeof item.subKey !== 'undefined' ? item.subKey : '';
        _column.chart = typeof item.charts !== 'undefined' ? item.charts : '';
        _column.assetId = typeof item.assetId !== 'undefined' ? item.assetId : '';
        _column.dateRange = typeof item.timestamp !== 'undefined' ? item.timestamp : '';

        if (!item.visible_for_user_group) {
          item.visible_for_user_group = [this.userInformation.main_group];
        }

        const _columnWidth = (typeof item.column_width !== 'undefined') ? item.column_width : '100px';
        const _disableTitle = typeof item.disable_title !== 'undefined' && item.disable_title;

        const _linkPrefix = (typeof _column.link !== 'undefined' && typeof _column.link.prefix !== 'undefined') ? _column.link.prefix : null;
        const _linkField = (typeof _column.link !== 'undefined' && typeof _column.link.field !== 'undefined') ? _column.link.field : null;
        const _linkSuffix = (typeof _column.link !== 'undefined' && typeof _column.link.suffix !== 'undefined') ? _column.link.suffix : null;
        const _iotOnlineTime = (typeof item.iot !== 'undefined' && typeof item.iot.onlineTime !== 'undefined') ? item.iot.onlineTime : null;
        const _iotColor = (typeof item.iot !== 'undefined' && typeof item.iot.color !== 'undefined') ? item.iot.color : null;
        if (item.contextMenuOptions) {

          item.contextMenuOptions.inputOptions.forEach((option, index) => {
            _contextMenuOptions += (typeof option !== 'undefined') ? `${option},` : '';
          });
          item.contextMenuOptions.link.forEach((option, index) => {
            _contextMenuPrefix += (typeof option.prefix !== 'undefined') ? `${option.prefix},` : '';
            _contextMenuField += (typeof option.field !== 'undefined') ? `${option.field},` : '';
            _contextMenuSuffix += (typeof option.suffix !== 'undefined') ? `${option.suffix},` : '';
          });
          _contextMenuLinksLength = item.contextMenuOptions.link.length;
        }

        if (item.visible_for_user_group[0].match(this.userInformation.main_group)) {
          gridColumns.push(html`
            <vaadin-grid-column
              path='${item.id}'
              subKey='${_column.subkey}'
              initialSort='${item.initialSort}'
              header='${item.title}'
              sort='${item.sort}'
              sortPath='${item.sortPath}'
              filter='${item.filter}'
              iconSrc='${_column.src}'
              iconTitle='${_column.title}'
              iconStyle='${_column.style}'
              linkPrefix='${_linkPrefix}'
              linkField='${_linkField}'
              linkSuffix='${_linkSuffix}'
              iotColor='${_iotColor}'
              iotOnlineTime='${_iotOnlineTime}'
              chart='${_column.chart}'
              assetId='${_column.assetId}'
              dateRange='${_column.dateRange}'
              contextMenuPrefix='${_contextMenuPrefix}'
              contextMenuField='${_contextMenuField}'
              contextMenuSuffix='${_contextMenuSuffix}'
              contextMenuOptionsLength='${_contextMenuOptionsLength}'
              contextMenuLinksLength='${_contextMenuLinksLength}'
              contextMenuOptions='${_contextMenuOptions}'
              width='${_columnWidth}'
              columnAlign='${item.column_align}'
              disableTitle='${_disableTitle}'
              .headerRenderer='${this.__searchAndFilterHeaderRenderer}'
              .renderer='${this._columnRenderer}'
            >
            </vaadin-grid-column>`);
        }
      }
    });

    return html`
      <vaadin-grid visible-rows='1' theme='row-stripes wrap-cell-content no-border' ?loading='${this.loading}' aria-label='${this.gridTitle}' .items='${this.gridItems}' ?multi-sort='${this.multiSort}'>
        ${gridColumns}
      </vaadin-grid>
      <paper-fab class='fab-item-left'
                 @click='${e => this._onDownloadCsvClick(e)}'
                 icon='add'
                 title='Export to CSV'></paper-fab>
    `;
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  __searchAndFilterHeaderRenderer(root, column) {
    const _path = column.getAttribute('path');
    const _title = column.getAttribute('header');
    const _initialSort = column.getAttribute('initialSort');
    const _filter = column.getAttribute('filter');
    const _sort = column.getAttribute('sort');
    const _sortPath = column.getAttribute('sortPath');
    const _disableTitle = column.getAttribute('disableTitle');
    if (_disableTitle) {
      render(html``, root);
    }

    let _vaadinGridSorter;
    let _vaadinGridFilter;

    if (_sort !== 'undefined' && _sort) {
      if (_initialSort !== 'undefined') {
        _vaadinGridSorter = html`
          <vaadin-grid-sorter id='sorter_${_path}' path='${_sortPath !== 'undefined' ? _sortPath : _path}'
                              direction='${_initialSort}'></vaadin-grid-sorter>
        `;
      } else {
        _vaadinGridSorter = html`
          <vaadin-grid-sorter path='${_sortPath !== 'undefined' ? _sortPath : _path}'></vaadin-grid-sorter>`;
      }
    }

    if (_filter !== 'undefined' && _filter) {
      _vaadinGridFilter = html`
        <vaadin-grid-filter path='${_path}'>
          <vaadin-text-field
            id='filter_${_path}'
            slot='filter'
            focus-target
            theme='small'
            placeholder='${_title}'
            @value-changed='${e => e.target.parentNode.value = e.detail.value}'>
          </
          >
        </vaadin-grid-filter>`;
    } else {
      _vaadinGridFilter = html`
        <vaadin-grid-column
          path='${_path}'
          class='header'>${_title}
        </vaadin-grid-column>
      `;
    }

    render(html`
      ${_vaadinGridSorter}
      ${_vaadinGridFilter}
    `, root);
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _columnRenderer(root, column, rowData) {
    const _path = column.getAttribute('path');
    const _subKey = column.getAttribute('subKey');
    const _iconSrc = column.getAttribute('iconSrc');
    const _iconTitle = column.getAttribute('iconTitle');
    const _linkPrefix = column.getAttribute('linkPrefix');
    const _linkField = column.getAttribute('linkField');
    const _linkSuffix = column.getAttribute('linkSuffix');
    const _chart = column.getAttribute('chart');
    const _assetId = column.getAttribute('assetId');
    const _dateRange = column.getAttribute('dateRange');
    const _iotColor = column.getAttribute('iotColor');
    let _contextMenuPrefix = column.getAttribute('contextMenuPrefix');
    let _contextMenuField = column.getAttribute('contextMenuField');
    let _contextMenuSuffix = column.getAttribute('contextMenuSuffix');
    const _contextMenuLinksLength = column.getAttribute('contextMenuLinksLength');
    let _contextMenuOptions = column.getAttribute('contextMenuOptions');
    const _iotOnlineTime = column.getAttribute('iotOnlineTime');
    const _columnAlign = column.getAttribute('columnAlign');

    let _link = null;
    let _inputOptions = null;
    const _vaadinItem = [];
    let _output = createGridOutput(_path, rowData);
    const _title = createGridOutput(_path, rowData);
    if (_subKey !== '') {
      _output = html`<b>${_output}</b><br />${rowData.item[_subKey]}`;
    }


    // TODO: testing against empty string?
    if (_linkField !== 'null') {
      _link = `${_linkPrefix}${rowData.item[_linkField]}${_linkSuffix}`;
    }

    let _vaadinGrid;
    /**
     * Create Icon and/or Link
     */

    if (_contextMenuField !== '' && _contextMenuOptions !== '') {

      for (let i = 0; i < Number(_contextMenuLinksLength); i++) {
        // get the string from Prefix Field / Suffix until ,
        _link = `${_contextMenuPrefix.substr(0, _contextMenuPrefix.indexOf(','))}${_contextMenuField.substr(0, _contextMenuField.indexOf(','))}/${rowData.item[_contextMenuSuffix.substr(0, _contextMenuSuffix.indexOf(','))]}`;

        // get the string for the label until ,
        _inputOptions = _contextMenuOptions.substr(0, _contextMenuOptions.indexOf(','));
        // create the vaadin-item
        _vaadinItem.push(html`
          <vaadin-item theme='custom'>
            <a href='${_link}'>${_inputOptions}</a>
          </vaadin-item>
        `);

        // delete the used string
        _contextMenuPrefix = _contextMenuPrefix.substr(_contextMenuPrefix.indexOf(',') + 1);
        _contextMenuSuffix = _contextMenuSuffix.substr(_contextMenuSuffix.indexOf(',') + 1);
        _contextMenuField = _contextMenuField.substr(_contextMenuField.indexOf(',') + 1);
        _contextMenuOptions = _contextMenuOptions.substr(_contextMenuOptions.indexOf(',') + 1);

      }
      _vaadinGrid = html`
        <vaadin-context-menu open-on='click'>
          <div style='text-align:${_columnAlign}'>
            <iron-icon icon='${_iconSrc}' style='cursor: pointer;'></iron-icon>
          </div>
          <template>
            <vaadin-list-box>
              ${_vaadinItem}
            </vaadin-list-box>
          </template>
        </vaadin-context-menu>
      `;
    } else if (_path === 'icon' && _link !== null) {
      _vaadinGrid = html`
        <a title='${_iconTitle}' id='${_title}' class='title' href='${_link}'>
          <div style='text-align:${_columnAlign}'>
            <iron-icon icon='${_iconSrc}'></iron-icon>
          </div>
        </a>`;
    } else if (_path === 'icon' && _link === null) {
      _vaadinGrid = html`
        <div title='${_iconTitle}' id='${_title}' style='text-align:${_columnAlign}'>
          <iron-icon icon='${_iconSrc}' style='cursor: pointer;'>
          </iron-icon>
        </div>`;
    } else if (_link !== null) {
      _vaadinGrid = html`
        <a title='${_title}' id='${_title}' href='${_link}'>${_output}</a>`;
    } else if (_path === 'iotLabel') {
      _vaadinGrid = html`
        <span title='${rowData.item[_iotOnlineTime]}' id='${rowData.item[_iotOnlineTime]}'
              class='circle ${rowData.item[_iotColor]}'></span>
        <span class='suffix'>${_output}</span>`;
    } else if (_path === 'trend') {
      _vaadinGrid = html`
        <span>${_output}</span>`;
    } else {
      _vaadinGrid = html`
        <span title='${_title}' id='${_title}'>${_output}</span>`;
    }
    /**
     * create charts in an grid
     */
    if (_chart !== '') {
      // dot at machineId is needed in edge. Without machineId is null
      _vaadinGrid = html`
        <ld-availability-swimlane-chart .machineId='${rowData.item[_assetId]}'
                                        .dateRange='${rowData.item[_dateRange]}'></ld-availability-swimlane-chart>`;
    }

    render(html`
      ${_vaadinGrid}
    `, root);
  }



  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  calculateHeight() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const vaddinGridTable = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('vaadin-grid');
      if (vaddinGridTable !== null) {
        this._height = `${vaddinGridTable.shadowRoot.querySelector('#table').clientHeight}px`;
        vaddinGridTable.setAttribute('style', `height:${this._height}`);
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  _onDownloadCsvClick(e) {
    let dataTable = null;
    const vaddinGridContent = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('vaadin-grid');
    if (vaddinGridContent !== null) {
      dataTable = vaddinGridContent.shadowRoot.querySelector('#table');
    }

    // console.log(dataTable);
    const exporter = new TableCSVExporter(dataTable, vaddinGridContent);
    const csvOutput = exporter.convertToCSV();
    const csvBlob = new Blob([csvOutput], { type: 'text/csv' });
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvBlob);
    const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');

    anchorElement.href = blobUrl;
    anchorElement.download = 'table-export.csv';
    anchorElement.click();
  }


}

customElements.define('ld-grid', LdGrid);
```